# If I have a program which uses 2FA (Authy) to verify my connection, am I able to gather the 2FA code automatically?

Tags: authy

I have a program. It uses 2FA to log in, and I am trying to make an API which uses the program. I am having trouble finding any answers on google, probably because I am using the wrong key words (The search "Authy API" or "2FA API" yields results to how to implement Authy, not how to gather the 2FA code to sign in)

If I am googling the wrong thing, how should I word what I am looking to find? I appreciate any help :)

Comment: The keyword you should probably use is `TOTP`. I can't tell what language you are using, but chances are your programming language has a `TOTP` package

Comment: Ooooh okay. Thank you for the tip! I am using PHP, and I would assume it has one as well, I just did not know what to call it. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Adding 2FA to an account is intended to stop automatic logins and require a user to produce a code from something they have (in this case, their phone number and authorised device), so side-stepping this is not supported or recommended.

You can only get the code from the device you have registered, or via SMS or phone call. It is TOTP, as Evert suggests, but the secret is generally not shared with you (it is sent to the Authy application over an encrypted channel and cannot be retrieved from the app either).